# Why am i getting <function myfunction.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001EFDE355310>

Tags: lambda

I have used the code :
def myfunction(x):
return lambda x: x*10

print(myfunction(10))

i am unable to understand why i am getting output :
<function myfunction.. at 0x000001EFDE355310>

Answer (score 0):

When you return a lambda you're returning a function (a first class object) and not the value itself.  `print(myfunction(10)(10)` might work.  Also this question could be improved with details of your context.  I'm guessing this is python but there's not really enough here to go by in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
# The following two implementations have equal results
# 1. don't use anonymous functions


def f(x):
    return x * x
# 2.using anonymous functions


def make_lambda(n):
    return lambda x: x * x


def main():
    num = 10
    #x = f(num)
    x = make_lambda(num)(num)
    print("Square of function of 10 is ", x)
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```